# How to create 360 degree image view with captured images in Android?

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, 360-degrees

I am developing application in native android. And I want to implement Google View like 360 degree image view by capturing the images from the camera.

Comment: DId you ever hear of the word `degree`? Then please use it.

Comment: Reading the  [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) about not including chit-chat in your questions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this requirement of showing 360 degree view of an object. 
You can do this using LayeredList and identifying the scroll gesture. You will need images of the object in all angles in the layered list.

Found this answer which should easily solve your problem:

[Create a 360 degree, interactive product preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345013/create-a-360-degree-interactive-product-preview)

Comment: Could you please help me for the same scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use now google Cardboard NDK to show.
https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/c/quickstart