# 360 degree interactive image preview in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, preview, 360-degrees

I was wondering how to achieve the 360 degree preview of image in flutter, like for product.

i did saw the below thread :

[Create a 360 degree, interactive product preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345013/create-a-360-degree-interactive-product-preview)

but how to do it in flutter ? does anyone knows what it's called in proper term and how to achieve it for android and ios ?

Comment: can anyone anwer this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugin might satisfy or help you, this is [flutter_imageview360](https://pub.dev/packages/imageview360) you can add an array of images and precache it and you can use it easily.